# Multi-threaded applications will crash at random if it is locking function not set in openssl

Tags: multithreading, openssl

As observed the following thread support API are removed in openssl 1.1

CRYPTO_set_locking_callback, CRYPTO_set_id_callback, CRYPTO_num_locks,
CRYPTO_set_dynlock_create_callback, CRYPTO_set_dynlock_lock_callback,
CRYPTO_set_dynlock_destroy_callback, CRYPTO_get_new_dynlockid,
CRYPTO_destroy_dynlockid, CRYPTO_lock - OpenSSL thread support

how to set crypto dynlocking for multithread application openssl 1.1. please share me if any reference example available.

Thanks,

Comment: What do you need exactly? You can always just write than read in alternance on the same thread with the same SSL struct. Than create different SSL struct for other threads. This avoids the need to have one thread per call. You can always set underlying sockets to non-blocking.

Comment: I am migrating openssl 1.0 to 1.1, as per observation, in openssl  1.1 the crypto locking support APIs removed( ex: CRYPTO_num_locks). Is there any limitation in openSSL 1.1 ?

Comment: To be clear, you can use SSL in multithreaded applications without CRYPTO_num_locks. CYPTO_num_locks is just in the case where you read and write with the same SSL struct on 2 different threads. If you use the same socket with multiple SSL struct, you can have several connections in multiple threads. You can always have mutexes or spin locks protecting your reading and writing I guess.